# JComboBox Index and database id comparison

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

`MySQL query > select * from area_detail;
+-----------+---------------+--------+
|area_id    |area_name      |place_id|
+-----------+---------------+--------+
|1          |place1_area1   |1       |
|3          |place1_area2   |1       |
|5          |place1_area3   |1       |
|6          |place2_area1   |2       |
|10         |place2_area2   |2       |
|17         |place3_area1   |3       |
|19         |place1_area4   |1       |
+-----------+---------------+--------+`

i have two JComboBox named as cbPlace and cbArea.... cbPlace displays the places and cbArea displays the areas under corrosponding place....

the main problem is when i want to get the corrosponding id of area that i selected. ComboBox gives me its own index like 1 2 3 4 5 so on...

i want to get result like ... if i click place1_area3 from cbArea comboBox it should return me id as 5(area_id) but not 3(cbArea.getSelectedIndex()).

and when i select place_2 in cbPlace combo box... and place2_area1 in cbArea combo box... it gives me id as 1(cbArea.getSelectedIndex())... but i want 6 as id...

how can i achieve so?

when i click place1 in cbPlace combo box and place1_area1 in cbArea combo box... it gives me id as 1... because in that case index of combo box i also 1.... ONLY IN THIS CASE...

but whwn ever i click any other place_area it gives me wrong results....
Help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom Object that contains the ID and the display text in the same Object. Then the combo box can display one value but your program can use another value.

There are two basic approaches for accomplishing this:

1. Create a custom renderer. See: [Combobox With Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/)
2. Use the toString() method of your custom Object. See [Combobox With Hidden Data](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/)

Most people would suggest the renderer approach is better, just don't forget about the KeySelectionManager.